# Radar Chart, Chart.js v3.2 labels customization

Tags: chart.js, radar-chart, chart.js3

how can i customize labels in radar chart?

i'm not refer to legend's labels, but the voice at the vertex of the radar chart

in particular font and color

i search a lot but i found soluton for older version, and only for color property

I just tried to use `pointLabels` property but don't work.
Could someone help me?

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMDhx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved through the following `options`:

```
scales: {
  r: {
    pointLabels: {
      color: 'green',
      font: {
        size: 20,
        style: 'italic'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I must admit that I didn't find the solution in the Chart.js documentation either. Therefore, I logged the entire chart to the console (`console.log(chart)`) and searched for `"scales"` to finally find the `pointLabels` default values.

Please take a look at below runnable sample and see how it works:

```js
new Chart('radar-chart', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Eating', 'Drinking', 'Sleeping', 'Designing', 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      r: {
        pointLabels: {
          color: 'green',
          font: {
            size: 20,
            style: 'italic'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: solution of `console.log(chart)` is a sample solution but that can be used for all problems like mine, when it's not explicit in documentation how to set chart property!